# Classes and Dynamically Allocated Array- Read access violation

Tags: c++

Takeaway from my issue:
Make sure you initialize the dynamic array in the constructor and not in the body of the class.

---

I am coming across a read access violation when I am trying to assign a local int variable the value of an array. The array is actually a pointer that is dynamically allocated and initialized in another class. I'm not sure what I am missing, if someone could help me I would greatly appreciate it:

Edit: I have fixed an earlier mistake where I called the array out of index, but I am still getting a read error.

Edit#2: I have tried the same snippet of code below without using pointers, and it works. However, when I dynamically allocate pointers, my program crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Discretization {
public:
    int Number_Elements, Number_Nodes;
    int *Ji = new int [Number_Elements];
    int* Jj = new int[Number_Elements];
    double* x = new double[Number_Nodes], * y = new double[Number_Nodes];

    Discretization() {

        Number_Elements = 8;
        Number_Nodes = 9;


        Ji[0] = 1; Jj[0] = 2;
        Ji[1] = 2; Jj[1] = 3;
        Ji[2] = 3; Jj[2] = 4;
        Ji[3] = 2; Jj[3] = 5;
        Ji[4] = 3; Jj[4] = 6;
        Ji[5] = 6; Jj[5] = 7;
        Ji[6] = 7; Jj[6] = 8;
        Ji[7] = 7; Jj[7] = 9;

        x[0] = -8.327; y[0] = -35.040;
        x[1] = 0; y[1] = -35.040;
        x[2] = 0; y[2] = 0;
        x[3] = -8.327; y[3] = 0;
        x[4] = 8.327; y[4] = -35.040;
        x[5] = 8.327; y[5] = 0;
        x[6] = 25.778; y[6] = 0;
        x[7] = 25.778; y[7] = 5.986;
        x[8] = 25.778; y[8] = -5.986;

    }
};


class GeometricProperties : public Discretization {

public:


    void AddVar(int Current_Element) {


        int Node_m = Ji[Current_Element] - 1; //Returns the first node of the element
        int Node_n = Jj[Current_Element] - 1; //Returns the second node of the element


        //Retruns local x coordinate of node m and n
        double Node_m_x = x[Node_m];
        double Node_n_x = x[Node_n];
    }

    GeometricProperties() {

        AddVar(1);
    }
};



int main() {

    GeometricProperties myobj;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Ji` has valid indices from `0` to `1`. `2` is not a valid index.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have fixed that , but I am still getting a read access error once I compile

Comment: Okay well that's not the only place where you access index `n` of an `n` element array. Valid indices for an `n` element array are `0` to `n - 1`.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I have tried a different code (with the actual example I am trying to solve) using static arrays, and it works. However, when I try to use dynamically allocated arrays, the program crashes. I have updated the code of the problem, and I am sure that it works when using static arrays.

Comment: Do you know how to use your debugger? Single step through your code, line by line, and make sure each relevant variable has the value you expect at each step.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I did, the variable would read something like "-18455181" but I wouldn't know where to go from there

Comment: What variable had that value? What correct value was that variable supposed to have? At what point was that variable supposed to have that correct value? Go to the point in the code where the correct value was supposed to be assigned and find out why it's not being assigned that.

Comment: Read this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thank you for the resource, I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of `GeometricProperties` calls `AddVar(2)`, which means `CurrentElement` is 2. But `Ji` has size 2, so you can only index 0 and 1.

Which means you are indexing `Ji` out of bounds. This is UB, and your program could crash.

You need to fix all such examples of UB. Even if your program has UB in code that is never run, the program is wrong.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I have fixed it, but I am still having a read access error

Comment: How about `Jj[2] = 3;`?

Comment: Hey @Cigien, I have updated the code to the actual example I am trying to solve. It works if you use static arrays, but crashes when I switch over to dynamic arrays

Comment: You haven't initialized `Number_Elements`. Reading from that is UB.

Comment: Omg yes. I moved the initialization to the constructor and it worked. Thank you so much, I overlooked that. By the way what does UB stand for?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour. It means the program can do *anything* it wants. It can even give the right answer :)